# MySQL query optimization - multiple INNER JOIN and WHERE clauses

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, inner-join, where-clause

```
SELECT C.cellName,L.opcond,CR.value as CellRise,CF.value as CellFall,FP.value as FallPower, 
      RP.value as RisePower, CR.whend from CELLPROPERTYFACT F 
                        INNER JOIN LIBRARY L on L.libraryID = F.libraryID 
                        INNER JOIN CELL C on C.cellID = F.cellID 
                        INNER JOIN CELLRISETEMPLATE CR on CR.cellID = C.cellID 
                        INNER JOIN CELLFALLTEMPLATE CF on CF.cellID = C.cellID 
                        INNER JOIN RISEPOWERTEMPLATE RP on RP.cellID = C.cellID 
                        INNER JOIN FALLPOWERTEMPLATE FP on FP.cellID = C.cellID 
                        where C.cellName LIKE '%' 
                            AND FP.fromP = RP.fromP 
                            AND CR.fromP = CF.fromP 
                            AND RP.fromP = CR.fromP 
                            AND FP.fromP = CF.fromP 
                            AND FP.toP = RP.toP 
                            AND CR.toP = CF.toP 
                            AND RP.toP = CR.toP 
                            AND FP.toP = CF.toP 
                            AND CR.whend = RP.whend 
                            AND CF.whend = FP.whend 
                            AND CR.whend = FP.whend 
                            AND CF.whend = RP.whend 
                            AND CR.whend = CF.whend 
                            AND FP.whend = RP.whend 
                            AND RP.related_pin = FP.related_pin 
                            AND L.workWeek LIKE '%'
                            AND L.opcond LIKE '%'
```

How can I optimize the query? is it using left join better than inner join so that I can have multiple ON statement in left join? My query is very slow and take around 2min to finish

Comment: 1) your missing a group by.  2) do you want the avg CR value in CELLRISETEMPLATE or after all the joins occur possibly skewing results (which is what's happening now) 3) where's the execution plan?  I'd like to know if it's applying the criteria after the joins which will inherently be slower... and why... do you need `like '%'` it serves 0 value and actually takes longer; unless the engine is smart enough to ignore it. Keep in mind the engine has to take num of rows in each table * num each other so if you have 10 rows in each table... 10^7 it's possibly generating 10,000,000 rows then filter

Comment: Showing sample data and expected results would help as well.  or an SQLFiddle.com setup with the data/structure.

Comment: You can have multiple join predicates in an inner join as well as left join, and based on your where clause I would say they most of them should form part of the join predicates. This will not make one iota of difference in terms of performance, but it should improve the legibility of your query.

Comment: @xQbert I think you are on the right track with requesting plans etc, however you are hugely mistaken if you the way a query is executed is by executing the `FROM` and all the `JOIN`s before applying the `WHERE`, so the logic that the number of records could ascend to 10m before being filtered is flawed. `SELECT * FROM A, B WHERE A.ID = B.ID` is *exactly* the same as `SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON B.ID = A.ID`

Comment: Have you tried to put "EXPLAIN" before the rest of the query? What are your indexes?